# Array inside another array with the name of a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one values that i want to place inside an array. And that array must go inside another array with a specific name. The problem is that i am having problems in how to do it

This is what i want:

array:

```
[ testeuser@mail.com: [value:3]]
```

i want the name variable of the first array to be name with the email of the user.

This is what i have tried:

```
referralHistory;
  referralSelfValue = [];

this.referralSelfValue = [{value: 3}];
 this.referralHistory = [newUser.email: [{ this.referralSelfValue}]];
```

basicly i want the referralHistory to be an array, that have antoher array in it, with the newUSer.email to be the name of the array that have the this.referralSelfValue

Comment: please add valid data structures. what does not work? (maybe write all without `this`?)

Comment: `this.referralHistory['newUser.email'] = {value: this.referralSelfValue} `

Comment: You probably need to figure out first how arrays and objects work in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Javascript; what you can do is creating an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "testeuser@mail.com": {
      value: 3
    }
  },
  {
    "foo@bar.com": {
      value: 7
    }
  }
]
```

or just an object like this:

```
{
  "testeuser@mail.com": {
    value: 3
  },
  "foo@bar.com": {
    value: 7
  }
}
```

Depending on the structure you want, you can do:

```
this.referralHistory = [];
this.referralSelfValue = 3;
this.referralHistory.push({ [newUser.email]: { value: this.referralSelfValue } });
```

or

```
this.referralHistory = {};
this.referralSelfValue = 3;
this.referralHistory[newUser.email] = { value: this.referralSelfValue };
```